# how to create more realistic explosions

Tags: java, android, animation

right now, for an explosion, i am just showing 3 images in a for loop, is there any better way to create a more realistic explostion? thanks.

Comment: Better images perhaps. You can get some good explosions from just images. Overlaying smoke and shrapnel also helps the realism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try blitting a sequence of pre-rendered bitmaps combined with a few single pixel "sparks" that fly from the origin. ParticleIllusion (which isn't free) lets you generate some very nice looking explosions and save them as a sequence of pngs.

Answer (score 2):

Google for "particle system"

Comment: I think MK means 'look up particle system in Google'.

Comment: ... which is actually a helpful answer, since the question did not mention particle systems at all, and they *can* be used to create more realistic explosions.

Comment: particle systems are also quite cpu intensive, something that most android devices have plentiful of

Comment: +1 First hit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bank of 10 or 15 images that pick randomly from to dynamically create new sequences

Answer (score 0):

any of the free tools from here could help: http://hasgraphics.com/tag/explosion/